# Como configurar tipo date em JS

Tags: javascript

estou tentando preencher um input do tipo date, através de uma função JS
estou tentando algo do tipo:

```
id('nascTit').value = 2005-05-15;
```

mas aparece o seguinte erro:

The specified value "yyyy-MM-dd" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Alguém sabe a forma correta de passar a data?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Quéal  o retorno da função `id`? Você passou a data como string? Porque `2005-05-15` é um cálulo igual a 1985

Comment: o que é `id('')` é uma função?

Comment: faltou aspas na data. Não?

Comment: não foi aspas que faltou, essa função na verdade usava o document.getElementById, eu não estava entendendo como funcionava, mas valeu galera..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mim deu certo dessa forma:

```js
document.getElementById("data").value = '2005-05-15';
```

```html
<input type="date" id="data" name="data" />
```

Comment: muito obrigado Virgílio, funcionou aqui e me ajudou entender umas coisas hehe